# Is there a way to find out which wonders have already been built?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

When choosing what to research the wonder is a major point. Not knowing if a wonder has been built or not can make choosing research frustrating. I can write down the wonders that haven been build on a piece of paper as they are announced, but is there a better way?

Comment: I am wondering this too. Yes there is a list under each player on the diplomacy screen but it does not miserable it much better. I would've though that they would disappear from the tech screen as they are built. That would be really handy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the Diplomacy screen, it lists each factions' Wonders.  Everyone gets a Headquarters, but after that, you can see the ones they have built.  It won't show you what they are currently building, though, so there's no way to use that to not waste production on the same Wonder.

Comment: Although this is not really comfortable it is better than to have no idea at all.

Comment: What happens if another faction completes a wonder which you are currently building? Do you automatically lose all production points spent towards that wonder?

Comment: Some as in every other CIV. Your progress is converted to Money (Energy).

Comment: Had that happen to me last night. I had one turn left, and then another civ completed it during turn processing. Not happy.